# Number of ordered pair $(a,b)$ such that ${ab\over a+b}=n$ ...

Tags: limits, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, natural-numbers

> Number of ordered pair $(a,b)$ of natural numbers such that ${ab\over a+b}=n$ (n $\in \mathbb{N}$) is $a_n$ then find , $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n\over n^2}$.

MY attempt :
Suppose the case where $n=2^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ . Then ,  ${ab\over a+b}=n$ is equivalent to $(a-2^k)(b-2^k)=2^{2k}$ . In this case $a_n=4k$  and thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n\over n^2}=0$

Now I have an intuition (from observations) that ${a_n\over n^2}$ would be maximum when $a_n$ is a power of 2 , and if bigger factors (like $3,5,etc$) are included then the ratio ${a_n\over n^2}$ would decrease. And thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n\over n^2}=0$ for any $n$

But I am not able to think of a solid mathematical proof for this .

Could someone please help me solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $ab/(a+b)=n \implies (n-a)(n-b)=n^2$

Comment: I have seen that , I also used it for the case I have taken Edit : I just realized the solution , $a_n$ can not be more than 2n , thus that limit will be 0. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

As already remarked in the comments, the integer solutions of $\frac{ab}{a+b}=n$ are the integer solutions of $(a-n)(b-n)=n^2$, so they are given by $(a,b)=\left(d+n,\frac{n^2}{d}+n\right)$ for any integer divisor $d$ of $n^2$.

The wanted limit is zero since the following Dirichlet series is clearly convergent:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\tau(n^2)}{n^2}=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{\tau(p^2)}{p^2}+\frac{\tau(p^4)}{p^4}+\ldots\right)=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{3}{p^2}+\frac{5}{p^4}+\ldots\right) $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\tau(n^2)}{n^2}=\prod_{p}\frac{p^2(p^4-1)}{(p^2-1)^3} =\frac{\zeta(2)^3}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{5\pi^2}{12}. $$